# Conditionally run command in init.d service script stop() on shutdown/reboot in CentOS6

Tags: centos, services, init-script, sysvinit

I have a service script in CentOS 6.10 that needs to touch a file when `service myservice stop` is called by the user or process, but *not* when stop() in the script is invoked by shutdown or reboot by `initd`. The service script is based on the template found on any CentOS system.

I imagine the best way of doing that is to have an `if` statement in the `stop()` method that checks whether or not the system is going down, but what would I check to find that out? `runlevel` 0 or 6 perhaps? Is there a better way of doing this than checking the system runlevel?